# Has there been a change in Google maps for mobile?

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile

I am having trouble getting Google Maps to work on my mobile website  [Here](http://yellowgreenmedia.nl/2/contact/routeplanner.php) is my google maps direction page that i have been using for a while now. [Here](http://yellowgreenmedia.nl/2/contact/route-code.txt) is the code in a txt file

The problem is that google maps doesn't show the route anymore but just the fronpage of google maps mobile.

Have there been some changes that i don't know about, this used to always work?

Thanks

Dave

Comment: We share the exact same problem. maps.google.com/m seems to no longer be. This said, so far have found out that m.google.com/maps seems to work better but still doesnt work for form submission to me

Answer (score 0):

make sure your form has a saddr and an eaddr fields (i have mine set to hidden) and change the form action just simply to "http://maps.google.com", no need for "m" or "directions", it'll just figure it all out now, which action it should take, based on the user agent I guess.

This will however, on mobile platforms, prompt an activity picker on android or launch google maps automatically on iPhone.

From what Im seeing at this point in the game, the onyl way around forcing anything is to write your own parser for the Google Directions API, using a combination of cURL and the json_decode function of PHP

:\ sadly